# Question of Differentiation/Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

An ice cube melts and decreases in volume at a rate of \begin{align} &10.8cm^3s^{-1} \end{align} and it's length decreases at rate of\begin{align} 0.5cms^{-1}\end{align} find its width. Ans: 2.68

Using logic I was able to create the equation: \begin{align}3(0.5x^2)=10.8\end{align}
x being height, height=width (cube)

But then this is a Differentiation/Integration question... and I don't understand how its principles are related to this question. Please explain and show me the correct equation :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the side of the ice cube at any instant be $x$

Notice, the volume of the ice cube having side $x$ at any time $t$ $$V=x^3$$ Now, differentiating both the sides w.r.t. time $t$ as follows $$\frac{d}{dt}(V)=\frac{d}{dt}(x^3)$$ $$\frac{dV}{dt}=3x^2\frac{dx}{dt}$$ Now, setting the value of rate of decrease in volume, $\frac{dV}{dt}=-10.8$ & rate of decrease in side $\frac{dx}{dt}=-0.5$ in the above equation, we get  $$-10.8=3x^2(-0.5)$$     $$x^2=\frac{36}{5}$$ $$x=\frac{6}{\sqrt {5}}\approx 2.68 \ cm$$
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{width of ice cube}=\frac{6}{\sqrt {5}}\approx 2.68 \ cm}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the side of cube and $V$ be its volume $V = x^3$. Differentiating both sides with respect to time
$$\frac {\Bbb dV} {\Bbb dt} = \frac {\Bbb d x^3} {\Bbb dt} = 3x^2 \frac {\Bbb dx} {\Bbb dt} \tag{chain rule} .$$
Now you know $ \frac {\Bbb dV} {\Bbb dt} = 10.8$ and $\frac {\Bbb dx} {\Bbb dt} = 0.5$. You get the same equation.